# Avoid early finalization of ref class which owns native resource

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, c++-cli

Consider the following wrapper in C++/CLI that provides a managed API and uses a native API (just a C int for illustrative purposes):

```
public ref class A
{
public:

    A()
    {
        native = new int;
        *native = 0;
    }

    !A() // finalizer
    {
        delete native;
        native = nullptr;
    }

    ~A() // destructor
    {
        this->!A();
    }

    void Increase()
    {
        int *otherNative = native; // for illustrative purpose
        // (1) Garbage collector might work here
        *otherNative++; // (2) operation on native object
        // (3)
    }

private:
    int *native;
};
```

Consider a simple client in C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Increase();
    }
}
```

At (1) in the code, the garbage collector might kick in, and collect
"non-reachable objects". From the book "Expert C++/CLI" by Marcus Heege (2007), and also from
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100813-00/?p=13153 I learned that
"non-reachable objects" include objects whose only reference are still in scope, but not used anymore.
So an object can be garbage-collected before its last reference goes out of scope.
In case this confuses you, here's an example:

```
void Method()
  { 
      Y y = SomehowCreateY();
      int z = 123;
      y->m();
      z++; // "y" still in scope, but can be garbage collected here
      blabla();
  }
```

For the wrapper example, it means that the garbage collector might call the
finalizer at or during (1) and/or (2), so the native object will
be deleted while or before it is used in (2).

Both the book and the blogpost recommend to put `GC.KeepAlive(this)`
at (3) in the example code to avoid this problem.

So basically the semantics of object aliveness in C++/CLI is quite tricky, and we do not think we can write reliable wrappers this way since we can easily forget to write a `GC.KeepAlive(this)`.

While I have good sources that this tricky semantics is indeed present, these sources
are rather old. My question:

1. Is this tricky semantics still the case in newer version of C++/CLI?
2. If not, I'd like a good reference so that I can be sure of it, since it's hard to test.
3. If yes, is there a less error-prone way to deal with it?

Comment: No! To call Increase you must have a valid reference. Nobody can call Increase when there is no reference to it. Or did I miss something. Who should execute the function Increase without a used reference?

Comment: @xMRi Yes, in the example we have a valid reference to call `Increase`, that is `a`. However, when we reach (1) inside `Increase`, such reference is not used anymore, so the GC can finalize that object, which would cause `native` to be deleted and the statement at (2) would be using an invalid pointer.

Comment: No. When you are inside the execution of Increase, the must be a caller that hold a reference to the object. Or? How should someone execute Increase without having a reference to it?

Comment: In this case the caller method is `Main`. It holds a reference to the object at the moment when it calls `Increase`. After it calls `Increase`, `Main` does not uses `a` any more. Inside `Increase`, `this` is only used in the first line to access `native`. So, after (1) nobody uses the object any more, and the GC can call the finalizer. I also thought this was impossible, I mean, finalizing an object when one of its own methods is executing.. well it is possible. It is a JIT optimization, and that's why `GC::KeepAlive` exists.

Comment: @xMRi the runtime environment has an optimizer which can inline methods, so there is not necessarily a call at this point and no need to keep an object in memory when you can hold the values of its variables in CPU registers. So the OP’s description is rather the tip of the iceberg, as an object’s “use” at runtime is not what you think to be an object’s use from looking at the source code. In absence of explicit barriers, an object may get collected while it is not only “in scope” but also having plenty of apparent use of it.